# In Android How to Set Horizontal Bar Chart RightAxis (YAxis) label show properly in MP Chart lib

Tags: android, kotlin, mpchart

[image: How can set YAxis value in middle of bar chart]

I was try to same code like multiple bar chart vertically it work but i need to show same as horizontal but it not show proper getting issue in YAxis.
YAxis lable is not show starting of the bar chart start i need to set it in middle of the chart.

i need to show like Below
[image: i need to show like this]